# When trying to convert an .e00 file into a shapefile with ogr2ogr, getting "ERROR 4: This looks like a compressed E00 file"

Tags: shapefile, grass-gis, ogr2ogr, compression, e00

When I ran this command:

```
ogr2ogr topo.shp flowe86hyp.e00
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR 4: This looks like a compressed E00 file and cannot be processed directly. You may need 
to uncompress it first using the E00compr library or the e00conv program.
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `flowe86hyp.e00' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> GMT
  -> SQLite
  -> DODS
  -> ODBC
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> PCIDSK
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> Geomedia
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> PDF
```

I've done some research on `e00compr` & `e00conv` so far, not a lot, but some, and have so far not been able to find a simple download that lets me build/make/install the program(s) on a mac. The `e00compr` I found here (https://github.com/fd00/yacp) on github had some kind of weird makefiles (apparently according to its README) for cygwin but none that I was able to use for the `make` command on my mac. And I found some e00compr source code at one point but it was all microsoft builds.

Anyway, I'm looking to use something like Grass, ogr2ogr, or some other command line tool to convert this e00 into shp and apparently am needing to uncompress it somehow. I've gone ahead and hosted a sample of the `.e00` file on google drive here: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5inC0VAuhH1Qm9OUGhGUFNOdk0/edit?usp=sharing) in case any of you would like to inspect it.

Comment: Although it doesn't help others, if you need just this dataset, I was able to convert it to a coverage in ArcGIS for Desktop. Email me if you want it: my username here at esri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ogr2ogr apparently doesn't work on MAC OS X in this case, I install and test (indicated in [GDAL: Arc/Info Binary Coverage](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_avcbin.html)):

(-> to build the packages -> open terminal, cd to the folder and type `make`)

#### 1) [AVCE00](http://avce00.maptools.org/avce00/index.html) (Arc/Info (binary) Vector Coverage <-> E00 Library)

> - avcexport' is a command-line executable that takes an Arc/Info binary coverage as input and converts it to E00.
>
>   - `avcexport input_cover output_file`
>   - input_cover is the path to the Arc/Info coverage to read from
>   - output_file is the name of the E00 file to create. If the file already exists then it is overwritten.
>   - Passing "-" as output_file will send the output to standard output (stdout).

Test -> error:

```
    $ avcexport flowe86hyp.e00 test.e00 
    ERROR 4: Invalid coverage (flowe86hyp.e00): directory does not appear to contain any supported vector coverage file.
```

#### 2) and [E00compr](http://avce00.maptools.org/e00compr/index.html) (A Library to Read/Write Compressed E00 Files, reported by you but downloaded from [e00compr-1.0.1.tar.gz](http://avce00.maptools.org/dl/e00compr-1.0.1.tar.gz).)

> - E00Compr is an Open Source (i.e. Free!) ANSI-C library to compress and uncompress Arc/Info Export (E00) files.
>
>   - e00conv' is a command-line executable that takes a E00 file as input (compressed or not) and copies it to a new file with the requested compression level (NONE, PARTIAL or FULL).
>   - `e00conv input_file output_file [NONE|PARTIAL|FULL]`
>   - input_file is the name of the E00 file to read from.
>   - output_file is the name of the file to create. If the file already exists then it is overwritten.
>   - The last argument is optional and specifies the compression level to use when creating the output file (one of NONE, PARTIAL or FULL). The default is NONE (uncompressed).

Test -> success:

```
    $ e00conv flowe86hyp.e00 test.e00
    $ ogr2ogr topo.shp test.e00
    Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'FLOWE86HYP#' to 'FLOWE86HYP'
    Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'FLOWE86HYP-ID' to 'FLOWE86H_1'
    Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'DESCRIPTION' to 'DESCRIPTIO'
    ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
    Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'FLOWE86HYP#' to 'FLOWE86HYP'
    Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'FLOWE86HYP-ID' to 'FLOWE86H_1'
    ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
    Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'FLOWE86HYP#' to 'FLOWE86HYP'
    Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'FLOWE86HYP-ID' to 'FLOWE86H_1'
```

And the result is many shapefiles in a folder named topo.shp

[image]

The layers are named as follows (from [GDAL: Arc/Info Binary Coverage](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_avcbin.html)):

> 1. A label layer (polygon labels, or free standing points) is named LAB if present.
> 2. A centroid layer (polygon centroids) is named CNT if present.
> 3. An arc (line) layer is named ARC if present.
> 4. A polygon layer is named "PAL" if present.
> 5. A text section is named according to the section subclass.
> 6. A region subclass is named according to the subclass name

In QGIS:

[image]

I hope that it will help you

Comment: Great! Simply had to run `make` inside the folder (placed in a semi-long-term location), then added this: `export PATH=/Users/daviddouglas/Develop/e00compr-1.0.1:$PATH` to the bottom of my `~/.bash_profile`, then reloaded shell and the `e00conv` command now works